# Azure iot edge modules development autoreload

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

While developing an iot edge module, I found that development process is a bit slow, and that was because I was rebuilding my app for every single change, the iotedgehubdev uses docker-compose internally, and while docker supports live reload through volumes, I didn't find any documentation / people complaining about that issue. So, is there a way to make edge module development quicker by enabling live reload feature ?

Comment: If you would like to use Azure IoT EdgeHub Dev Tool, I suggest you also add a new feature request here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/issues

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT EdgeHub Dev Tool does not support live reload feature as of today.

Please add a new feature request in the repo: https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/issues

Comment: Created the issue thanks: https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev/issues/349